# How to solve Prometheus chart Ingres/Service mapping?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

Just installed stable/prometheus chart with below values and I'm able to access the server frontend from pods but not from host's web browser.

My **values.yaml**:

```
alertmanager:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - localhost/alerts

server:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - localhost/prom

pushgateway:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - localhost/push
```

I use nginx ingress and ingresses get created but for some unknown reason, it doesn't seem to map to the service.

**Some data:**

I'm able to access the server from ingress pods (also all others) via default and dns service names:

```
kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-5cb489cd48-t4dgv -- sh
/etc/nginx $ curl prometheus-server.default.svc.cluster.local
<a href="/graph">Found</a>

/etc/nginx $ curl prometheus-server
<a href="/graph">Found</a>
```

List of active ingresses created by the chart:

```
kubectl get ingress
NAME                      HOSTS       ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
nginx-ingress             localhost   localhost   80      37h
prometheus-alertmanager   localhost   localhost   80      43m
prometheus-pushgateway    localhost   localhost   80      43m
prometheus-server         localhost   localhost   80      43m
```

List of active service resources:

```
kubectl get svc
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes                      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      37h
nginx-deployment                ClusterIP      10.100.1.167     <none>        80/TCP                       37h
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.109.57.131    localhost     80:32382/TCP,443:30669/TCP   36h
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.107.91.35     <none>        80/TCP                       36h
php-deployment                  ClusterIP      10.105.73.26     <none>        9000/TCP                     37h
prometheus-alertmanager         ClusterIP      10.97.89.149     <none>        80/TCP                       44m
prometheus-kube-state-metrics   ClusterIP      None             <none>        80/TCP,81/TCP                44m
prometheus-node-exporter        ClusterIP      None             <none>        9100/TCP                     44m
prometheus-pushgateway          ClusterIP      10.105.81.111    <none>        9091/TCP                     44m
prometheus-server               ClusterIP      10.108.225.187   <none>        80/TCP                       44m
```

On the other hand, if I declare subdomain as an ingress host, Prometheus is accessible:

```
alertmanager:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - alerts.localhost

server:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - prom.localhost

pushgateway:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - push.localhost
```

Am I doing something wrong or there's some sort of issue with this?
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Version of Helm and Kubernetes:
Helm 3.0.3 / Kubernetes 1.15.5 (Docker for Mac, MacOS Catalina)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your scenario and by running some tests I understood that this is not going to work in the way you want it to work. This is not the right way to implement it.

Let's dive into it a bit.

You can add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` in your ingresses as in this example:

```
$ kubectl get ingresses. myprom-prometheus-pushgateway -oyaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  creationTimestamp: "2020-02-18T09:51:32Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: prometheus
    chart: prometheus-10.4.0
    component: pushgateway
    heritage: Helm
    release: myprom
  name: myprom-prometheus-pushgateway
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "3239"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/myprom-prometheus-pushgateway
  uid: 499372f4-52b1-4b37-982c-b52e70657d37
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myprom-prometheus-pushgateway
          servicePort: 9091
        path: /push
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.168.39.251
```

After adding this, you are going to be capable to access as you intended. Unfortunately after doing this you're going to face a new problem. If we inspect the html output from a curl command we can see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <title>Prometheus Pushgateway</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico?v=793293bdadd51fdaca69de5bb25637b0f93b656b">

    <script src="/static/jquery-3.4.1.min.js?v=793293bdadd51fdaca69de5bb25637b0f93b656b"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js?v=793293bdadd51fdaca69de5bb25637b0f93b656b"></script>
    <script src="/static/functions.js?v=793293bdadd51fdaca69de5bb25637b0f93b656b"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=793293bdadd51fdaca69de5bb25637b0f93b656b">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/prometheus.css?v=793293bdadd51fdaca69de5bb25637b0f93b656b">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap4-glyphicons/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.min.css?v=793293bdadd51fdaca69de5bb25637b0f93b656b">
  </head>
```

As can be seen, we have `/static/jquery-3.4.1.min.js` for example, so this is going to redirect your browser to a different location. The problem is that you don't have this location.

That's why i suggest you to avoid using path and stick tom your secondary solution that involves using a sub-domain.

```
alertmanager:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - alerts.localhost

server:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - prom.localhost

pushgateway:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - push.localhost
```

Comment: Use a subdomain rather than a subdirectory shouldn't be an answer here. The issue wasn't resolved.